# TRESTResponse sends different parameter value to web service method

Tags: rest, delphi, post, encoding, delphi-xe7

I created an application in Delphi XE7 that consumes a web service function or method. I use `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest` and `TRESTResponse`. I use `POST` for sending parameter values to the web service.

One of my parameters is a string value and this is the actual sample value:

```
此消息是从delphi应用程序发送的
```

When I receive it in my API, the value turns out with this actual value:

```
k64m88`6Ff2FNCEdelphi^94u28z0B^8FSD101v84
```

The english value of the parameter is `"this message was sent from delphi application"`.

Sample code:

```
client := TRESTClient.Create('here lies the rest api url');
client.HandleRedirects := True;
client.AllowCookies := False;

response := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);

request := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
request.Client := client;
request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPost;
request.AddParameter('message',Trim(pMessage),TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
request.Timeout := 3000000;
request.SynchronizedEvents := True;

request.Response := response;
```

When I send parameters without Chinese characters, everything is fine.

Comment: This report may be related: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18143, since the debugger uses the same components. It was fixed in Delphi Tokyo 10.2.2, and I believe the fix was a change made to the TRESTRequestParameter.ToString method in the REST.Client unit

Comment: Hi @Dave Nottage. Thanks for the reply, actually i cannot switch to delphi tokyo 10.2.2. What I did is I switched to indy for raw requests configuration. Everything worked fine.